# Residue for 1/t^(1/2)

Tags: complex-analysis

Given
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\log^2 t-\pi^2}{t^{\frac{1}{2}}(1+t^2)}. $$

I know there are $i$ and $-i$ as poles in this integral.

But how can I dealt with $1/t^{1/2}$ part? Is $t=0$ is a pole for it?

Can I times $t^{1/2}$ to numerator and denominator to solve this?

Comment: $t^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is not a function on the whole $\mathbb{C}$, you can define it on some subsets (they must not contain a path going around $0$) by choosing a so called branch. Since it is not defined where we need, you cannot talk about the residue of the 1-form $\frac{(\log^2 t-\pi^2)dt}{t^{\frac{1}{2}}(1+t^2)}$

Comment: Ok that's clear. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea: substitute $y^2=t\implies 2ydy=dt\;$ , and your integral becomes

$$2\int_0^\infty\frac{\log^2(y^2-\pi^2)}{(1+y^4)}\,\,y\,dy$$

Clearer now?

Comment: @CameronBuie Thanks, edited...though the OP didn't even wrote parentheses for hte logarithm's argument...